# How to concatenate mongodb properties in nodejs variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, variables, nosql

I'm attempting to concatenate the mongodb query in a variable in node js depending on my condition. I'm unable to concatenate the mongodb attributes here. I've included the output I'm looking for below. I understand that the + icon only concatenates strings.

- *What i need is:*

> ```
> var query;
> query += db.collection('collection_name');
> query += query.find();
> if(project == true)
> {
>     query +=query.project(project_parameter);
> }
>
> if(limit == true)
> {
>     query += query.limit();
> }
>
> // Output needed if i run the query variable
> db.collection('collection_name').find({id:1}).project({_id:1}).limit(10).toArray();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If these functions support chaining, then you can do something similar to this:

```js
let query = db.collection('collection_name')
query = query.find()
if (project === true) {
  query = query.project(project_parameter)
}

if (limit === true) {
  query = query.limit()
}
```

This is because calling a function on `db.colllection('collection_name')` returns a modified object that you can keep calling functions on.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Ben Grant, i tried this method but not working for me